# Fingerprint or other, what method was used to unlock the Android smartphone?

Tags: android, xamarin, fingerprint

As Xamarin application, I want to know what kind of authentication method was used to unlock the smartphone. Is there a API for that? Is there a log somewhere ?

Comment: The `BiometricManager.CanAuthenticate` (if given security requirements are available, highly API dependent) and `KeyguardManager.IsDeviceSecure` (PIN, pattern or password is set)  can tell you if certain security requirements can be met, but you as an app developer do not have access to the actual method(s) that the device/user has enabled or is using.

Comment: Ok thank you SushiHangover, I see your point. And what about the log. No intrusion, no hack, I just want to know the last owner authentication method.

Comment: The only non-root "log" is `logcat`, it has a FIFO finite size and I do not know if the OS logs any authentication specific events, but you can look: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/debugging/android-debug-log?tabs=windows